# What's a more rubyesque way of doing this?

Tags: ruby, oauth, idioms

I'm checking a session hash for some oAuth values and then setting them if they don't exist. This is my existing code:

```
unless session[:oauth][:request_token].nil? && session[:oauth][:request_token_secret].nil?
    @request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(@client, session[:oauth][:request_token], session[:oauth][:request_token_secret])
end
```

...but it's nasty and doesn't seem particularly rubyish. Is there a more idiomatic way of writing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps just use some variables?

```
oauth = session[:oauth]
token, secret = oauth.values_at :request_token, :request_token_secret

if token && secret
  @request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(@client, token, secret)
end
```

Note that I've replaced your `unless obj.nil?` with an `if obj` since `nil` is falsy anyway. Unless you expect to have `false` as a valid value, this is a typical Ruby idiom.

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I tried all sorts of things with `[ :request_token, :blah ].each` but, the simpler the better!

Answer (score 2):

I'd write:

```
oauth = session[:oauth]
if (token = oauth[:request_oken]) && (secret = oauth[:request_token_secret)
  @request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(@client, token, secret)
end
```

Or:

```
token, secret = session[:oauth].values_at(:request_token, :request_token_secret)
@request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(@client, token, secret) if token && secret
```

Comment: Like my `values_at`, eh? `;)`

Comment: swear I updated it before I saw yours... I re-added my first snippet when I saw it was the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way:

```
session[:oauth].tap do |h|
  [h[:request_token], h[:request_token_secret]].tap do |t1, t2|
    @request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(@client, t1, t2) if t1 and t2
  end
end
```

Actually, I would be using the following method that I defined and usually use for myself.

```
class Object
  def chain &pr; pr.call(self) end
end
```

Then, you can avoid the nesting, and the code will be a little better:

```
session[:oauth]
.chain{|h| [h[:request_token], h[:request_token_secret]]}
.tap{|t1, t2| @request_token = OAuth::RequestToken.new(@client, t1, t2) if t1 and t2}
```